# How to go to parent operator in JSONPath?

Tags: jsonpath

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/jsonpath/wiki/ExprSyntax), there is no equivalent syntax for this?

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Example

```
{ ...
   attrib1: {},
   attrib2: []
...
}
```

When I'm looping in `attrib2` path, i would like to get some info from `attrib1`. How would i do it in this case?